# How to add a constant* during JSON deserialization using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson and JsonDeserializer.
When I deserialize to MyClass, you need to set the MyContext class.
I used to use static final constants, but I cannot use that for my reason (I need to use instance constants).
I am doing deserialization using ObjectMapper.

Here is the code I tried.

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using=MyClassDeserializer.class)
class MyClass {
    @JsonIgnore
    private final MyContext context;
    
    public final int foo;
    public final String bar;
}

class MyClassDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyClass> {
    
    @Override
    public PacketContainer deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException {
            MyContext myContext = (MyContext) deserializationContext.getConfig().getAttributes().getAttribute("context");
            // It seems no attributes has registered.

            doSome(myContext.foo); // NullPointerException occurs
            // ...
    }
}

class MyContext {
    private String foo;
    private int bar;

    // getter(); setter();
}

// main()
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Context context = new Context();
context.setFoo("foo");
context.setBar(0);

HashMap<String, Context> contextSetting = new HashMap<>();
contextSetting.put("context", context);


mapper.getDeserializationConfig().getAttributes().withSharedAttributes(contextSetting);
mapper.getDeserializationContext().setAttribute("context", context);
```

How can I dynamically set constants during deserialization?

I am using a translator.
Thank you.

Comment: You want to just read the `context` object in the deserializer , (no need for the `contextSetting` map you are using) ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, but I was thinking of using it because I need to give MyContext from outside when instantiating MyClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stands in the fact that you are trying to register your `context` object in your `mapper`'s config in the wrong way: you can use the [`DeserializationConfig`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationConfig.html) *withAttribute* method that returns a new configuration including your `context` object  and then set your mapper with the new configuration:

```
MyContext myContext = new MyContext();
myContext.setFoo("foo");
myContext.setBar(0);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setConfig(mapper.getDeserializationConfig()
      .withAttribute("context", myContext));
```

After that the `context` object is available in the your `JsonDeserializer` class like you wrote:

```
MyContext myContext = (MyContext) deserializationContext.getConfig()
                                 .getAttributes()
                                 .getAttribute("context");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Everything worked fine. I didn't know it was immutable. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Peyang You are welcome, unfortunately it is not so clear from the documentation.